# How can I install laminate flooring without removing base molding?

Tags: laminate

I am looking for a suggestion about not removing my base molding and laying laminate under it. It will be much easier than removing because of risk of damage ,etc. , and I will put 1/4'' or 1/2'' corner round on top which I think looks good. Basically the molding is about 1/2'' thick. So I am wanting to go under that and 1/4'' from wall so how can I get that spacing and get it out after I get to the other side since it would be underneath ? I know I could just start it flush with molding since I am going to put round over on top but when I am hammering all the other pieces how do I keep it from sliding underneath and right against wall?

Answer (score 1):

Pick yourself up a [laminate flooring installation kit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Roberts-Laminate-and-Wood-Flooring-Installation-Kit-10-28/202832701), like this one.

[image]

It comes with spacers that can be placed between the already installed planks, and the base molding. The spacers will maintain the required gap, as you hammer the planks together.

The kit also includes a pull bar, and tapping block. Both of which will come in quite handy.

[image][image]

Installing laminate (and any hardwood flooring) without removing the base molding is quite common.

Comment: Normally, one would then nail a bit of additional molding (a quarter-round, for example) at the base of the existing molding to cover the gap.

Comment: @keshlam That's true, and the OP has already said that's what they plan to do.